# Origin to 3D cursor not working for one mesh

Tags: 3d-cursor, origin

Following the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/PaTSfLdaGhw), at 16:55 I select the "frets" and I do "set origin to 3D cursor", but the origin stay in place and don't move. After a lot of search, I can't figure what is wrong. Can you help me ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like it has to do with the Z scale which is currently 0, but don't ask me why it makes it fail  ://   so just apply the scale

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! It works.

Answer (score 2):

As moonboots said, if I apply the scale the origin moves to 3D cursor.